# input date field should display month & year only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is while user selecting input date field then display only month and year not date.
i had tried mm/yy in my jquery but didn't worked for me.
here is my code.

```js
var onDateSelect = function(selectedDate, input) {
  if (input.id === 'Start') { //Start date selected - update End Date picker
    $("#End").datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
  } else { //End date selected - update Start Date picker
    $("#Start").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
  }
};
var onDocumentReady = function() {
  var datepickerConfiguration = {
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: onDateSelect
  };
  ///--- Component Binding ---///
  $('#Start, #End').datepicker(datepickerConfiguration);
};
$(onDocumentReady);  // jQuery DOM ready callback registration
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="Start" name="start" min="2000-03" required>
    <input type="text" id="End" name="start" min="2000-03" required>
```

I'm choose first date field it also should display month and year & second field do as same as first field except don't display previous date accordingly first date so it is working finely except displaying month & year

Comment: in datepicker do you want to show only `mm/yyyy` or in input field. Is this do you want [month and year picker](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/1446/)

Comment: only two input field who show month and year only if first selected one particular month & year then second field choose forward date only not previous accordingly first date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get use `mm/yy` to display only month and year ,also to you need to get date manually and then set in your datepicker. i.e :

```js
var onDateSelect = function(selectedDate, input) {
  if (input.id === 'Start') {
   //getting start date
    var start = $('#Start').datepicker("getDate");
    console.log("start - "+start);
    //setting it has mindate
    $("#End").datepicker('option', 'minDate', start);
  } else if(input.id === 'End'){ 
   //getting end date
    var end = $('#End').datepicker("getDate");
    console.log("end - "+end);
    //passing it max date in start
    $("#Start").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', end);
  }
};
var onDocumentReady = function() {
  var datepickerConfiguration = {
    onSelect: onDateSelect,
    dateFormat: "mm/yy",
  };
  ///--- Component Binding ---///
  $('#Start, #End').datepicker(datepickerConfiguration);
  
};
$(onDocumentReady); // jQuery DOM ready callback registration
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="Start" name="start" min="2000-03" required>
<input type="text" id="End" name="start" min="2000-03" required>
```

Answer (score 13):

Not a perfect solution, but you can use [<input type="month">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month).

---

## Example

```html
<label for="start">Start month:</label>

<input type="month" id="start" name="start"
       min="2020-08" value="2020-10">
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: Not supported some browser like Firefox etc